# move task to back not working properly android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B, to move from A to B you need to login. After I move to B I call finsih on A.

In B activity I call movetoBack when the back button is pressed. However when I recall my App it takes me back to A.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack (true);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you reverse? @Override public void onBackPressed() { moveTaskToBack (true); super.onBackPressed(); }

Comment: if you call super.onBackPressed . it will behave as normaly it does. while overriding you must remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't call `super`, which invokes the default implementation of the BACK button...which is to call `finish()` on the current Activity.  Just call `moveTaskToBack()` inside of your Override.

Comment: I love this site. Thanks alot