# moveTaskToBack(true) is not working when activity launchMode is singleInstance

Tags: android

In FragmentActivity moveTaskToBack(true) is not working when activity launchMode is singleInstance.

I have tried 
[move task to back not working properly android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313201/move-task-to-back-not-working-properly-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.

launchMode=singleTop

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    //  super.onBackPressed();
}
```