# Examples of when to use launchMode = "singleInstance"

Tags: android, single-instance, launchmode

I am looking for concrete examples of when to use `launchMode="singleInstance"`. Everywhere I read, it is said that there are very few occasions when it should be used. So I'm amazed I never see examples!!

The closest explanation I've found is [here](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) where it says:

> [it] should only be used in the applications that are implemented entirely as one activity

But if that is the case, I wonder why it is never phrased so concisely in official Android documentation.

So my question is:

1. Is this really the only case where `singleInstance` should be used?
2. Are there any situations where the above is NOT a good enough reason for using `singleInstance`?
3. Concrete examples where using `singleInstance` is a good idea
4. Undesirable side effects of using `singleInstance` inappropriately, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949782/movetasktobacktrue-is-not-working-when-activity-launchmode-is-singleinstance)

Comment: This article explain the launchMode in perfect way. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Answer (score 1):

According [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Navigation-and-Task-Stacks) article:

> Only one AlarmAlert activity at a time and it is always its own task.
>   Anything it might launch (if anything) becomes a part of a separate
>   task stack.

But this information is deprecated. I found that Marshmallow is using `com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerAlertFullScreen` as an activity with singleInstance launch mode.

```
<activity
             android:name="com.android.deskclock.timer.TimerAlertFullScreen"
             android:excludeFromRecents="true"
             android:theme="@style/TimerAlertFullScreenTheme"
             android:launchMode="singleInstance"
             android:showOnLockScreen="true"
             android:taskAffinity=""
             android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>
```

Here is the [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/marshmallow-release/AndroidManifest.xml).